# Compile time type determination in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, templates, types

A coworker recently showed me some code that he found online. It appears to allow compile time determination of whether a type has an "is a" relationship with another type. I think this is totally awesome, but I have to admit that I'm clueless as to how this actually works. Can anyone explain this to me?

```
template<typename BaseT, typename DerivedT>
inline bool isRelated(const DerivedT&)
{
    DerivedT derived();
    char test(const BaseT&); // sizeof(test()) == sizeof(char)
    char (&test(...))[2];    // sizeof(test()) == sizeof(char[2])
    struct conversion 
    { 
        enum { exists = (sizeof(test(derived())) == sizeof(char)) }; 
    };
    return conversion::exists;
}
```

Once this function is defined, you can use it like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class base {};
class derived : public base {};
class unrelated {};

int main()
{
    base b;
    derived d;
    unrelated u;

    if( isRelated<base>( b ) )
        std::cout << "b is related to base" << std::endl;

    if( isRelated<base>( d ) )
        std::cout << "d is related to base" << std::endl;

    if( !isRelated<base>( u ) )
        std::cout << "u is not related to base" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That's pretty damn cool voodoo.

Comment: If you are interested in those things, get a copy of Alexandrescus *"Modern C++ Design"*.

Comment: I think this is all over the place, e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631585/c-how-to-require-that-one-template-type-is-derived-from-the-other/2631677#2631677. Note that the test itself happens at compile-time, but you obtain the result at runtime (returning from a function) where you can hardly use it for anything useful.

Comment: It's a neat trick, but only for educational purposes. I'd never use anything like that in code I use because generally in good design you don't explicitly compare types.

Comment: ^^ I probably should never say "never". But yeah.

Comment: `boost::is_base_of`, `boost::is_base_and_derived`. It's fun, but fairly well known by now. Note that the boost examples allow you to get access to the information at compile time which is much more interesting :)

Comment: This is now a part of C++11's type traits
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It declares two overloaded functions named `test`, one taking a `Base` and one taking anything `(...)`, and returning different types.

It then calls the function with a `Derived` and checks the size of its return type to see which overload is called.  (It actually calls the function with the return value of a function that returns `Derived`, to avoid using memory)

Because `enum`s are compile-time constants, all of this is done within the type system at compile-time.  Since the functions don't end up getting called at runtime, it doesn't matter that they have no bodies.

Comment: `derived()` isn't there for saving memory - the `sizeof()` expression is evaluated at compile time anyway - it is one way of not requiring `Derived` to be default constructible (i.e. to avoid using `test(Derived())`).

Comment: @gf: I meant as opposed to declaring a pointer to a `Dervied`.

Answer (score 6):

I'm no C++ expert, but it looks to me like the point is to get the compiler to decide between the two overloads of `test()`. If `Derived` is derived from `Base` then the first one will be used, which returns `char`, otherwise the second one will be used - which returns `char[2]`. The `sizeof()` operator then determines which of these happened and sets the value of `conversion::exists` accordingly.

Comment: true..its only based on overload resolution.

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty cool but it doesn't actually work, because user-defined conversion is preferred to ellipsis match, and const reference can bind the temporary result of a user-defined conversion.  So `char*p; is_related<bool>(p);` would return `true` (tested in VS2010).

If you want to truly test for an inheritance relationship, a similar approach can be taken but using pointers instead of references.

Answer (score 5):

Is there any reason you wouldn't use something like this instead:

```
template<typename BaseT, typename DerivedT>
struct IsRelated
{
    static DerivedT derived();
    static char test(const BaseT&); // sizeof(test()) == sizeof(char)
    static char (&test(...))[2];    // sizeof(test()) == sizeof(char[2])

    enum { exists = (sizeof(test(derived())) == sizeof(char)) }; 
}
```

?

e.g.:

```
IsRelated<Base, Derived>::exists
```

That way you have access to the information at compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

By the way, you can use `__is_base_of` from "type_traits" introduced in `std::tr1` (MSCV 2008 compiler has intrinsics support for that).

Answer (score 1):

The original code will construct an object of Derived, it may brings unexpected result. Below work may be an alternative choice:

```
template<typename BaseT, typename CheckT>
inline  bool    isDerived(const CheckT &t){
    char    test(const BaseT   *t);
    char    (&test(...))[2];
    return  (sizeof(test(&t)) == sizeof(char) );
}
```