# Please help me understand this syntax (implementing static assert in C++)

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, metaprogramming

This syntax was used as a part of an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631585/):

```
template <bool>
struct static_assert;

template <>
struct static_assert<true> {}; // only true is defined

#define STATIC_ASSERT(x) static_assert<(x)>()
```

**I do not understand that syntax. How does it work?**

Suppose I do

```
STATIC_ASSERT(true);
```

it gets converted to

```
static_assert<true>();
```

Now what?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
STATIC_ASSERT(true);
```

indeed means

```
static_assert<true>();
```

which evaluates to nothing. `static_assert<true>` is just an empty structure without any members. `static_assert<true>()` creates an object of that structure and does not store it anywhere.

This simply compiles and does nothing.

On the other hand

```
STATIC_ASSERT(false);
```

means

```
static_assert<false>();
```

which results in compilation error. `static_assert` has no specialization for `false`. So a general form is used. But the general form is given as follows:

```
template <bool>
struct static_assert;
```

which is just a declaration of a structure and not its definition. So `static_assert<false>()` causes compilation error as it tries to make an object of a structure which is not defined.

Answer (score 9):

`static_assert<true>();` makes that

```
template <>
struct static_assert<true> {}
```

templated struct specialization temporary object creation being done - a call to constructor and later to a destructor that both will be hopefully eliminated by the optimizer since they do nothing. Since there's only a specialization for `true` and no generic version of the template struct all constructs that evaluate to `static_assert<false>();` will just not compile.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, i too found myself lost in this syntax.

Answer (score 4):

In the expression

```
static_assert<true>();
```

since `static_assert<true>` is a type, it will call the constructor of `static_assert<true>`. As `static_assert<true>` is specialized to an empty struct, nothing will be affected.

---

However, in

```
static_assert<false>();
```

as there is no specialization for `static_assert<false>`, the generic definition

```
template <bool>
struct static_assert;
```

will be used. But here, the type `static_assert<B>` is *incomplete*. So calling constructor of `static_assert<B>` will result in compilation error.

---

Therefore, this is called "static assert" as the statement will abort the compilation if the expression evaluates to `false`, similar to the [normal `assert()` function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_%28computing%29#Assertions_for_run-time_checking) that will kill the program in runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I guess it is about template specialization. STATIC_ASSERT(true) will compile successfully, because there is a definition (not just a declaration) of "static_assert< true >".

STATIC_ASSERT(false) will be rejected by the compiler, because there is only a declaration for "static_assert< false >" and no definition.

Update: for visual studio, STATIC_ASSERT(true) is ok, but STATIC_ASSERT(false) triggers the error: "error C2514: 'static_assert<__formal>' : class has no constructors [ with __formal = false ]"