# How do I ensure that two types have the same size?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2005

In my code, I want to ensure that `sizeof(a) == sizeof(b)`.

First approach was to let the preprocessor do the checking:

```
#if (sizeof(a) != sizeof(b))
#  error sizes don't match
#endif
```

which doesn't compile because of `fatal error C1017: invalid integer constant expression`. Okay. Understand.

Next try:

```
if(sizeof(a) != sizeof(b)){
  printf("sizes don't match\n");
  return -1;
}
```

Which results in a warning: `warning C4127: conditional expression is constant`.

Now, I'm stuck. Is there a warning-and-error-free way to make sure that the two structs `a` and `b` have the same size?

---

**Edit:** 
Compiler is Visual Studio 2005, Warning level is set to 4.

Comment: I've had this problem before trying to ensure that `double` is the same size as `__int64`. I ended up disabling that warning.

Comment: Use static assert - for example this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/3099445/57428

Comment: @sharptooth, question is tagged as `C`. Template tricks won't work here...

Comment: @eran: True, my bad. Yet there's an implementation of static assert that uses array typedefs - it should work in C.

Comment: Static Assert in C has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385515/static-assert-in-c/3385694

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Bad array size

```
// make sure sizeof(a) == sizeof(b):
int size_must_match[sizeof(a) == sizeof(b)];
// will fail if sizeof(a) == sizeof(b) evaluates to 0
// might produce warning: 'size_must_match' is not used 

// to suppress "'size_must_match' is not used", try:
size_must_match[0]; // might produce warning: "statement has no effect"
```

or

```
typedef int size_must_match[sizeof(a) == sizeof(b)];
```

## Bad compile-time arithmetic

In C++ is guaranteed that these constant expressions are evaluated by the compiler at compile-time, and I believe the same holds in C:

```
// make sure sizeof(a) == sizeof(b):
1 / (sizeof(a) == sizeof(b));
// might produce warning: "statement has no effect"

int size_must_match = 1 / (sizeof(a) == sizeof(b));
// might produce warning: 'size_must_match' is unused

assert (1 / (sizeof(a) == sizeof(b)));
// very silly way to use assert!
```

## Switch (just for fun)

```
switch (0) { // compiler might complain that the 
             // controlling expression is constant
case 0:       
case sizeof(a) == sizeof(b):
    ; // nothing to do
}
```

You get the idea. Just play around with this until the compiler is 100 % happy.

Comment: Googling around for a C static assertion might give you a pre-rolled one the compiler won't whine endlessly about.

Comment: @curiousguy: **very** nice approach :-) Using `int size_must_match = 1 / (sizeof(a) == sizeof(b));` followed by `if(!size_must_match) return -1;` to get rid of the `unused` warning.

Comment: @eckes also I think casting to void removes the warning: `(void)(1 / (sizeof(a) == sizeof(b));`

Answer (score 2):

The first case is explicitly forbidden according to `#if` documentation:

> The expression cannot use sizeof or a type-cast operator.

As for the warning, you can either ignore it (because you know your code is ok), disable it using a `#pragma`, or just take the condition out of the `if`:

```
bool sizeMatch = (sizeof(a) == sizeof(b));
if (!sizeMatch){
    printf("sizes don't match\n");
    return -1;
}
```

---

Edit: since disabling the error seems to have drawn some attention, here are a couple of ways to achieve that using [`#pragma warning`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
#pragma warning (push) 
#pragma warning (disable: 4127)
    if(sizeof(a) != sizeof(b)){
#pragma warning (pop) 
          // ...
```

The pop could obviously be done further down the code. Another option could be:

```
#pragma warning (disable: 4127)
    if(sizeof(a) != sizeof(b)){
#pragma warning (default: 4127)
```

Which will turn the warning back on without pushing and popping.

Either way, this code does look ugly. IMO, just using a `bool` to get the result of the `sizeof` comparison (as my first snippet shows) would be the cleanest solution.

Comment: "_The first case is explicitly forbidden_" That isn't surprising, the preprocessor does not know your types: it runs **before** the concept of types even exist! ;) "_As for the warning, you can either ignore it_" If you do that a regulary, it is more likely that you will miss an important warning.

Comment: @curiousguy, ignoring one warning doesn't mean you have to turn off your mind and ignore all other warnings from that point onward. But I mentioned that for completeness - I also offer two easy ways to prevent that specific warning, and it's one of them that I would personally use.

Comment: Perhaps consider pushing warning levels, ignore that warning, do the comparison and then pop the levels again. That's ugly but won't effect any legitimate warnings.

Comment: @SvenS, I didn't think the details of how you should use the pragma were required, but why not. Answer updated.

Comment: "_ignoring one warning doesn't mean you have to turn off your mind and ignore all other warnings from that point onward._" Ignoring **one** warning implies that the compiler will emit one message about "unused something" every time your compile this TU. You know there isn't a problem here, so every time you will ignore this warning and go straight to the other more interesting warnings. It means that will get used to see "unused something" messages, and you might not pay attention to another "unused something" warning in some other TU.

Comment: (continued) This "unused something" warning is probably easy to mentally parse; other compiler messages are not so easy to read, they sometimes look like line noise (especially in C++). But if you decide that warnings are acceptable, you cannot stop with just one warning without contradicting yourself. Every time you write something that makes really sense, such as the compiler doesn't see the point, you get an additional warning. It is not so easy to sort out the new warnings from the already seen warnings.

Comment: (continued) In the best case, you will be wasting time reading warning messages every time you compile a TU. In the worst case, you might miss a warning that uncovers a real programming error. This is why "unclean" compiles are considered bad. The obvious question is: why don't we have an interactive tool to confirm that a warning is unimportant to permanently suppress it?

Comment: @SvenS Another issue is the readability of such things `(disable: 4127)`. The intent of the `if` is clear, and it is obviously harmless. But when pragma are used to suppress warnings in other contexts, where it is not clear that the code is correct, not knowing what the warning was about (unless you remember the error numbers) doesn't help the maintenance programmer.

Comment: (continued) Another issue is that pragma are compiler-specific. Of course, you can use conditional compilation, but that makes the warning suppressing code even longer. Which leads us to the other problem: the visual clutter of all these '#' prefixed lines around a simple `if`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct tag {
int a;
};
main() {
    struct tag a,b;
        if(sizeof(a) != sizeof(b))
        printf("not");
    else
        printf("same");

}
```

this programs works fine without any warning...!!!

Comment: What warning level are you using? The error only appears on level 4.

Comment: Perhaps you use different warning levels, or you use different compilers? (Assuming eckes has no reason to lie to us ;))

Comment: GCC doesn't have this warning. Only Visual Studio does.

Comment: I believe OP was using Visual Studio 2005. Warnings vary from compiler to another.

Comment: @Mr.32: I'm not compiling with VS2005 for fun. Using GCC is not an option.

Comment: I think you should have a warning about the missing return type from `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to play hide and seek with the compiler and hide the constant conditional in places the compiler cannot see it, it's not the best way to suppress warnings. It will only make the code seem unnecessarily obscure for the next person who is going to maintain it.

If you need to suppress compiler warnings, please be explicit about it. In Visual Studio 2005, you are best off using pragmas:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e(v=vs.80).aspx