# Metaprogramming in C++ and in D

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, d

The template mechanism in C++ only accidentally became useful for template metaprogramming. On the other hand, D's was designed specifically to facilitate this. And apparently it's even easier to understand (or so I've heard).

I've no experience with D, but I'm curious, what is it that you can do in D and you cannot in C++, when it comes to template metaprogramming?

Comment: If they're both turing complete the answer is nothing :)

Comment: @awoodland: That's only true for a very limited definition of "do". By any normal definition, there are plenty of things which you can't do with C++ templates (writing to files for example - but I imagine you can't do that with template meta-programming in D either).

Comment: @awoodland: Turing tarpit, anyone? ;)

Comment: @Paul: Do you mean C++03 and earlier, or do you mean C++0x/C++11?

Comment: @Merhdad C++11 definitely adds some useful stuff to templates (such as variadic templates) which make it so that they're not quite as badly outmatched, but without some sort of conditional compilation like D has, they're still not ever close to D's templates. So, whether you're talking about C++11 or pre-C++11 is certainly relevant to the question, but it ultimately doesn't matter much.

Comment: @Mehrdad The 'best' C++, so I guess C++11.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The two biggest things that help template metaprogramming in D are template constraints and `static if` - both of which C++ could theoretically add and which would benefit it greatly.

Template constraints allow you to put a condition on a template that must be true for the template to be able to be instantiated. For instance, this is the signature of one of `std.algorithm.find`'s overloads:

```
R find(alias pred = "a == b", R, E)(R haystack, E needle)
    if (isInputRange!R &&
        is(typeof(binaryFun!pred(haystack.front, needle)) : bool))
```

In order for this templated function to be able to be instantiated, the type `R` must be an input range as defined by `std.range.isInputRange` (so `isInputRange!R` must be `true`), and the given predicate needs to be a binary function which compiles with the given arguments and returns a type which is implicitly convertible to `bool`. If the result of the condition in the template constraint is `false`, then the template won't compile. Not only does this protect you from the nasty template errors that you get in C++ when templates won't compile with their given arguments, but it makes it so that you can overload templates based on their template constraints. For instance, there's another overload of `find` which is

```
R1 find(alias pred = "a == b", R1, R2)(R1 haystack, R2 needle)
if (isForwardRange!R1 && isForwardRange!R2
        && is(typeof(binaryFun!pred(haystack.front, needle.front)) : bool)
        && !isRandomAccessRange!R1)
```

It takes exactly the same arguments, but its constraint is different. So, different types work with different overloads of the same templated function, and the best implementation of `find` can be used for each type. There's no way to do that sort of thing cleanly in C++. With a bit of familiarity with the functions and templates used in your typical template constraint, template constraints in D are fairly easy to read, whereas you need some very complicated template metaprogramming in C++ to even attempt something like this, which your average programmer is not going to be able to understand, let alone actually do on their own. Boost is a prime example of this. It does some amazing stuff, but it's incredibly complicated.

`static if` improves the situation even further. Just like with template constraints, any condition which can be evaluated at compile time can be used with it. e.g.

```
static if(isIntegral!T)
{
    //...
}
else static if(isFloatingPoint!T)
{
    //...
}
else static if(isSomeString!T)
{
    //...
}
else static if(isDynamicArray!T)
{
    //...
}
else
{
    //...
}
```

Which branch is compiled in depends on which condition first evaluates to `true`. So, within a template, you can specialize pieces of its implementation based on the types that the template was instantiated with - or based on anything else which can be evaluated at compile time. For instance, `core.time` uses

```
static if(is(typeof(clock_gettime)))
```

to compile code differently based on whether the system provides `clock_gettime` or not (if `clock_gettime` is there, it uses it, otherwise it uses `gettimeofday`).

Probably the most stark example that I've seen where D improves on templates is with a problem which my team at work ran into in C++. We needed to instantiate a template differently based on whether the type it was given was derived from a particular base class or not. We ended up using a solution based on [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631585/c-how-to-require-that-one-template-type-is-derived-from-the-other). It works, but it's fairly complicated for just testing whether one type is derived from another.

In D, however, all you have to do is use the `:` operator. e.g.

```
auto func(T : U)(T val) {...}
```

If `T` is implicitly convertible to `U` (as it would be if `T` were derived from `U`), then `func` will compile, whereas if `T` isn't implicitly convertible to `U`, then it won't. *That* simple improvement makes even basic template specializations much more powerful (even without template constraints or `static if`).

Personally, I rarely use templates in C++ other than with containers and the occasional function in `<algorithm>`, because they're so much of a pain to use. They result in ugly errors and are very hard to do anything fancy with. To do anything even a little bit complicated, you need to be very skilled with templates and template metaprogramming. With templates in D though, it's so easy that I use them all the time. The errors are much easier to understand and deal with (though they're still worse than errors typically are with non-templated functions), and I don't have to figure out how to force the language into doing what I want with fancy metaprogramming.

There's no reason that C++ couldn't gain much of these abilities that D has (C++ concepts would help if they ever get those sorted out), but until they add basic conditional compilation with constructs similar to template constraints and `static if` to C++, C++ templates just won't be able to compare with D templates in terms of ease of use and power.

Comment: You can declare variables of different types within `static if`. Extremely useful.

Comment: C++ now has template constraints and a variant of `static if`

Comment: yes: `if constexpr` and concepts

Answer (score 40):

I believe nothing is better qualified to show the incredible power (TM) of the D template system than [this renderer](http://h3.gd/ctrace/) I found years ago:

[image: The compiler output]

Yes! This is actually what is generated by the *compiler* ... it is the "program", and quite a colourful one, indeed.

#### Edit

The source seems to be back online.

Comment: Cool! Any idea where to get the source?

Comment: I seem unable to find it (I think I downloaded it some time ago). But even if I found it on one of my drives, I'm not sure it would be legal to share it. Perhaps one could ask the author to fix the link (it is *most* likely not intentionally broken).

Comment: As a side note, the source code there was written years ago (as mentioned in the accompanying page) - quite a lot of the code in there (particularly code in the meta/ directory) can be *vastly* simplified and shortened due to changes to D, even without going near compile time function execution.

Comment: @Jasu_M: The ray tracer you link to has to be called after compiling. This is a big difference to ctrace, I think. It is a big difference, if you can get your c++-template system to produce an executable that will print out an image on standard out, or if you can get your d-template system to get the *compiler* to *directly* produce the image.

Comment: Ah, so the compiler actually outputs RGB data, not a program. Ok, that's definitely something C++ can't do.

Comment: This is cool and pretty, but what's the practical application of it? I'm not going to learn D just to make a pretty picture that takes 7 hours to render.

Comment: @Justin: Congratulations on completely missing the point ;) It is cool, so it is upvoted more than the less cool, but more useful answer below. the question was “what can i do in d what i can’t in c++”. outputting rgb instead of a program is much farther away from what you can do in c++, so there is your answer.

Comment: @Jasu_M: Of course you can tweak metatrace so that it would output within error messages ;)

Comment: @JustinMorgan, That's like asking, "yeah, sending a fancy electrical signal across the country over a wire is cool and all, but what's the practical use of this silly, so-called _telegram_ thingy?  Ponies work just fine, don't they?"

Answer (score 27):

The best examples of D metaprogramming are D standard library modules that make heavy use of it vs. C++ Boost and STL modules.  Check out D's [std.range](https://www.dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html), [std.algorithm](https://www.dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html), [std.functional](https://www.dlang.org/phobos/std_functional.html) and [std.parallelism](https://www.dlang.org/phobos/std_parallelism.html).  None of these would be easy to implement in C++, at least with the kind of clean, expressive API that the D modules have.

The best way to learn D metaprogramming, IMHO, is by these kinds of examples.  I learned largely by reading the code to std.algorithm and std.range, which were written by Andrei Alexandrescu (a C++ template metaprogramming guru who has become heavily involved with D).  I then used what I learned and contributed the std.parallelism module.

Also note that D has compile time function evaluation (CTFE) which is similar to C++1x's `constexpr` but much more general in that a large and growing subset of functions that can be evaluated at runtime can be evaluated unmodified at compile time.  This is useful for compile-time code generation, and the generated code can be compiled using [string mixins](https://www.dlang.org/statement.html#MixinStatement).

Comment: For CFTE, you can read my blogpost for a more complete explanation: http://giovanni.bajo.it/2010/05/compile-time-function-execution-in-d/

Answer (score 14):

Well in D you can easily impose static [constraints on template parameters](http://www.d-programming-language.org/concepts.html) and write code depending on the actual template argument with [static if](http://www.d-programming-language.org/version.html#StaticIfCondition).
It's possible to simulate that for simple cases with C++ by using template specialization and other tricks (see boost) but it's a PITA and very limited cause the compiler doesn't expose many details about types.

One thing C++ really just can't do is sophisticated compile time code generation.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a piece of D code that does a custom-made `map()` which *returns its results by reference*.

It creates two arrays of length 4, *maps* each corresponding pair of elements to the element with the minimum value, and multiplies it by 50, and *stores the result back into the original array*.

Some important features to note are the following:

- The templates are variadic: `map()` could take any number of arguments.
- The code **is (relatively) short**! The `Mapper` structure, which is the core logic, is only 15 lines -- and yet it can do so much with so little. My point isn't that this is impossible in C++, but that certainly isn't as compact and clean.

---

```
import std.metastrings, std.typetuple, std.range, std.stdio;

void main() {
    auto arr1 = [1, 10, 5, 6], arr2 = [3, 9, 80, 4];

    foreach (ref m; map!min(arr1, arr2)[1 .. 3])
        m *= 50;

    writeln(arr1, arr2); // Voila! You get:  [1, 10, 250, 6][3, 450, 80, 4]
}

auto ref min(T...)(ref T values) {
    auto p = &values[0];
    foreach (i, v; values)
        if (v < *p)
            p = &values[i];
    return *p;
}

Mapper!(F, T) map(alias F, T...)(T args) { return Mapper!(F, T)(args); }

struct Mapper(alias F, T...) {
    T src;  // It's a tuple!

    @property bool empty() { return src[0].empty; }

    @property auto ref front() {
        immutable sources = FormatIota!(q{src[%s].front}, T.length);
        return mixin(Format!(q{F(%s)}, sources));
    }

    void popFront() { foreach (i, x; src) { src[i].popFront(); } }

    auto opSlice(size_t a, size_t b) {
        immutable sliced = FormatIota!(q{src[%s][a .. b]}, T.length);
        return mixin(Format!(q{map!F(%s)}, sliced));
    }
}


// All this does is go through the numbers [0, len),
// and return string 'f' formatted with each integer, all joined with commas
template FormatIota(string f, int len, int i = 0) {
    static if (i + 1 < len)
        enum FormatIota = Format!(f, i) ~ ", " ~ FormatIota!(f, len, i + 1);
    else
        enum FormatIota = Format!(f, i);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I wrote up my experiences with D's templates, string mixins, and template mixins: http://david.rothlis.net/d/templates/

It should give you a flavour of what is possible in D -- I don't think that in C++ you can access an identifier as a string, transform that string at compile time, and generate code from the manipulated string.

My conclusion: Extremely flexible, extremely powerful, and usable by mere mortals, but the reference compiler is still somewhat buggy when it comes to the more advanced compile-time metaprogramming stuff.

Comment: The latest version of dmd (the D compiler), released 3 days ago, fixes one of the two bugs I found. I've updated the article to suit.

Comment: I'm afraid your acticle lost me there as soon as I reached the code example for a "typed implementation of the relational algebra", since I am not yet very well versed in D or what it is you want to accomplish that could not be done with ordinary functions.

Comment: Qwertie: Consider the part in that first code sample that says "This should cause a compilation error" -- I don't know how to achieve that without using metaprogramming. Functions like "project" (π) are creating new types on the fly *at compile time* that can be checked by the compiler -- so if you say "ages[0].name" you get a compilation error, rather than a run-time error. (P.S. I am also not very well versed in D so I may have overcomplicated things.)

Answer (score 8):

String manipulation, even string parsing.

[This is a MP library](http://dsource.org/projects/scrapple/browser/trunk/dparser) that generates recursive decent parsers based on grammars defined in strings using (more or less) BNF. I haven't touched it in years but it used to work.

Answer (score 6):

in D you can check the size of a type and the available methods on it and decide which implementation you want to use

this is used for example in the [`core.atomic` module](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/druntime/blob/master/src/core/atomic.d#L628)

```
bool cas(T,V1,V2)( shared(T)* here, const V1 ifThis, const V2 writeThis ){
    static if(T.sizeof == byte.sizeof){
       //do 1 byte CaS
    }else static if(T.sizeof == short.sizeof){
       //do 2 byte CaS
    }else static if( T.sizeof == int.sizeof ){
       //do 4 byte CaS
    }else static if( T.sizeof == long.sizeof ){
       //do 8 byte CaS
    }else static assert(false);
}
```

Comment: In C++ you can check `sizeof` too although that would be better handled by a specialisation

Comment: Wouldn't that happen at runtime though, imposing overhead? In the D version that all happens at compile time. There's no branch.

Comment: A C++ compiler could optimize checks like this (though it is not guaranteed to), so this is not a great example. What you cannot do easily in C++ is something like `static if (is(T == string)) writeln(t ~ t); else writeln(t * 2);`. You can't do that in C++, first because you can't test the type so easily, and second because `x * 2` does not compile if x is a string, and `x ~ x` does not compile if x is a number.

Answer (score 3):

Just to counter the D ray tracing post, here is a C++ compile time ray tracer ([metatrace](https://github.com/phresnel/metatrace)):

[image]

(by the way, it uses mostly C++2003 metaprogramming; it would be more readable with the new `constexpr`s)

Comment: With D 2.0, the main difference is that the compile-time raytracer would look like ordinary D code, whereas the C++ raytracer is far longer and most developers wouldn't want to even try to understand it, let alone write a metaprogram of any significant size.

Comment: @Qwertie: That's perhaps right. With C++11, you can make very readable compile-time-metaprogramming, too. There is currently a caveat: A constexpr function must only use the ternary operator and recursion for flow control (e.g.: `constexpr int fac(int c) { return c<=1 ? 1 : c*fac(c-1); }`). Future C++ versions will probably provide a static if, too.

Comment: @Qwertie: And of course, the question was "what is possible", rather than "what is sane" :D

Comment: Fix the link please.

Comment: @nbro: Thx, did so :)

Answer (score 1):

There are quiet a few things you can do in template metaprogramming in D that you cannot do in C++. The most important thing is that you can do template metaprogramming WITHOUT SO MUCH OF A PAIN!