# How the new range-based for loop in C++17 helps Ranges TS?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, c++17

The committee changed the range-based for loop from:

- C++11:

  ```
  {
     auto && __range = range_expression ; 
     for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; 
         __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
         range_declaration = *__begin; 
         loop_statement 
     }
  }
  ```
- to C++17   :

  ```
  {        
      auto && __range = range_expression ; 
      auto __begin = begin_expr ;
      auto __end = end_expr ;
      for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
          range_declaration = *__begin; 
          loop_statement 
      } 
  }
  ```

And people said that this will make implementing Ranges TS easier. Can you give me some examples?

Comment: The only difference I can see is that 1. implementation requires __begin and __end to be of the same type. There is no such need for second implementation.

Comment: Yes. The proposal itself states in the Motivation:

The existing range-based for loop is over-constrained. The end iterator is never incremented, decremented, or dereferenced. Requiring it to be an iterator serves no practical purpose.

Loosening the type requirements of the range-based for loop gives users of the Ranges TS the best possible experience. 

I wonder what that best possible experience looks like. 

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0184r0.html

Comment: Mainly to support proxy end iterators I presume.

Comment: Ranges allows for sentinels as end markers (for example in null terminated strings), this wasn't possible if both __begin and __end were iterators.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### C++11/14 range-`for` was overconstrained...

The WG21 paper for this is [**P0184R0**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0184r0.html) which has the following motivation:

> The existing range-based for loop is over-constrained. The end
>   iterator is never incremented, decremented, or dereferenced. Requiring
>   it to be an iterator serves no practical purpose.

As you can see from the Standardese that you posted, the `end` iterator of a range is only used in the loop-condition `__begin != __end;`. Hence `end` only needs to be equality comparable to `begin`, and it does not need to be dereferenceable or incrementable.

### ...which distorts `operator==` for delimited iterators.

So what disadvantage does this have? Well, if you have a sentinel-delimited range (C-string, line of text, etc.), then you have to shoehorn the loop-condition into the iterator's `operator==`, essentially like this

```
#include <iostream>

template <char Delim = 0>
struct StringIterator
{
    char const* ptr = nullptr;   

    friend auto operator==(StringIterator lhs, StringIterator rhs) {
        return lhs.ptr ? (rhs.ptr || (*lhs.ptr == Delim)) : (!rhs.ptr || (*rhs.ptr == Delim));
    }

    friend auto operator!=(StringIterator lhs, StringIterator rhs) {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }

    auto& operator*()  {        return *ptr;  }
    auto& operator++() { ++ptr; return *this; }
};

template <char Delim = 0>
class StringRange
{
    StringIterator<Delim> it;
public:
    StringRange(char const* ptr) : it{ptr} {}
    auto begin() { return it;                      }
    auto end()   { return StringIterator<Delim>{}; }
};

int main()
{
    // "Hello World", no exclamation mark
    for (auto const& c : StringRange<'!'>{"Hello World!"})
        std::cout << c;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fbb84d60dd49c14) with g++ -std=c++14, ([**assembly**](https://godbolt.org/g/uf0hlV) using gcc.godbolt.org)

The above `operator==` for `StringIterator<>` is symmetric in its arguments and does not rely on whether the range-for is `begin != end` or `end != begin` (otherwise you could cheat and cut the code in half).

For simple iteration patterns, the compiler is able to optimize the convoluted logic inside `operator==`. Indeed, for the above example, the `operator==` is reduced to a single comparison. But will this continue to work for long pipelines of ranges and filters? Who knows. It is likely to require heroic optimization levels.

### C++17 will relax the constraints which will simplify delimited ranges...

So where exactly does the simplification manifest itself? In `operator==`, which now has extra overloads taking an iterator/sentinel pair (in both orders, for symmetry). So the run time logic becomes compile time logic.

```
#include <iostream>

template <char Delim = 0>
struct StringSentinel {};

struct StringIterator
{
    char const* ptr = nullptr;   

    template <char Delim>
    friend auto operator==(StringIterator lhs, StringSentinel<Delim> rhs) {
        return *lhs.ptr == Delim;
    }

    template <char Delim>
    friend auto operator==(StringSentinel<Delim> lhs, StringIterator rhs) {
        return rhs == lhs;
    }

    template <char Delim>
    friend auto operator!=(StringIterator lhs, StringSentinel<Delim> rhs) {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }

    template <char Delim>
    friend auto operator!=(StringSentinel<Delim> lhs, StringIterator rhs) {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }

    auto& operator*()  {        return *ptr;  }
    auto& operator++() { ++ptr; return *this; }
};

template <char Delim = 0>
class StringRange
{
    StringIterator it;
public:
    StringRange(char const* ptr) : it{ptr} {}
    auto begin() { return it;                      }
    auto end()   { return StringSentinel<Delim>{}; }
};

int main()
{
    // "Hello World", no exclamation mark
    for (auto const& c : StringRange<'!'>{"Hello World!"})
        std::cout << c;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/066f12dfd95af716) using g++ -std=c++1z ([**assembly**](https://godbolt.org/g/LJFldT) using gcc.godbolt.org, which is almost identical to the previous example).

### ...and will in fact support fully general, primitive "D-style" ranges.

WG21 paper [**N4382**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4382.pdf) has the following suggestion:

> **C.6 Range Facade and Adaptor Utilities [future.facade]**
>
> 1 Until it
>   becomes trivial for users to create their own iterator types, the full
>   potential of iterators will remain unrealized. The range abstraction
>   makes that achievable. With the right library components, it should be
>   possible for users to define a range with a minimal interface (e.g.,
>   `current`, `done`, and `next` members), and have iterator types
>   automatically generated. Such a range facade class template is left as
>   future work.

Essentially, this is equal to D-style ranges (where these primitives are called `empty`, `front` and `popFront`). A delimited string range with only these primitives would look something like this:

```
template <char Delim = 0>
class PrimitiveStringRange
{
    char const* ptr;
public:    
    PrimitiveStringRange(char const* c) : ptr{c} {}
    auto& current()    { return *ptr;          }
    auto  done() const { return *ptr == Delim; }
    auto  next()       { ++ptr;                }
};
```

If one does not know the underlying representation of a primitive range, how to extract iterators from it? How to adapt this to a range that can be used with range-`for`? Here's one way (see also the [**series of blog posts**](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) by @EricNiebler) and the comments from @T.C.:

```
#include <iostream>

// adapt any primitive range with current/done/next to Iterator/Sentinel pair with begin/end
template <class Derived>
struct RangeAdaptor : private Derived
{      
    using Derived::Derived;

    struct Sentinel {};

    struct Iterator
    {
        Derived*  rng;

        friend auto operator==(Iterator it, Sentinel) { return it.rng->done(); }
        friend auto operator==(Sentinel, Iterator it) { return it.rng->done(); }

        friend auto operator!=(Iterator lhs, Sentinel rhs) { return !(lhs == rhs); }
        friend auto operator!=(Sentinel lhs, Iterator rhs) { return !(lhs == rhs); }

        auto& operator*()  {              return rng->current(); }
        auto& operator++() { rng->next(); return *this;          }
    };

    auto begin() { return Iterator{this}; }
    auto end()   { return Sentinel{};     }
};

int main()
{
    // "Hello World", no exclamation mark
    for (auto const& c : RangeAdaptor<PrimitiveStringRange<'!'>>{"Hello World!"})
        std::cout << c;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eeb17d3fef056f1f) using g++ -std=c++1z ([**assembly**](https://godbolt.org/g/5QTPvS) using gcc.godbolt.org)

**Conclusion**: sentinels are not just a cute mechanism to press delimiters into the type system, they are general enough to [**support primitive "D-style" ranges**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18549717/819272) (which themselves may have no notion of iterators) as a zero-overhead abstraction for the new C++1z range-for.

Answer (score 39):

The new specification allows `__begin` and `__end` to be of different type, as long as `__end` can be compared to `__begin` for inequality. `__end` doesn't even need to be an iterator and can be a predicate. Here is a silly example with a struct defining `begin` and `end` members, the latter being a predicate instead of an iterator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// a struct to get the first word of a string

struct FirstWord {
    std::string data;

    // declare a predicate to make ' ' a string ender

    struct EndOfString {
        bool operator()(std::string::iterator it) { return (*it) != '\0' && (*it) != ' '; }
    };

    std::string::iterator begin() { return data.begin(); }
    EndOfString end() { return EndOfString(); }
};

// declare the comparison operator

bool operator!=(std::string::iterator it, FirstWord::EndOfString p) { return p(it); }

// test

int main() {
    for (auto c : {"Hello World !!!"})
        std::cout << c;
    std::cout << std::endl; // print "Hello World !!!"

    for (auto c : FirstWord{"Hello World !!!"}) // works with gcc with C++17 enabled
        std::cout << c;
    std::cout << std::endl; // print "Hello"
}
```

Comment: Yes. That is nice example, thank you. But I was trying to find a Ranges TS specific example.

Comment: @DimitarMirchev: The range TS does not actually define any ranges. It defines a number of algorithms that act on ranges, and Concepts TS concepts that allow one to write code that uses ranges. But Range TS v1 doesn't provide any actual *range types*. So there are no examples that can be provided.

Comment: @NicolBolas Why it is related to Ranges TS? I think it is because Ranges TS *supports* these asymmetric iterator/sentinel ranges.

Comment: @Yakk: Yes, the Range TS defines range concepts that permit iterator/sentinel pairing. But it doesn't define any actual ranges that use them. So the only thing one could show from the Range TS is a concept. Which simply says "iterator/sentinel pairings are OK," which is something we already know. It doesn't show an example of their *use*.

Comment: I gave an example in [n4128](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4128.html#an-iterables-end-may-have-a-different-type-than-its-begin). Also see the [appendix on sentinels and code generation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4128.html#appendix-1-sentinels-and-code-generation).